# How to find the full version of a song

Tags: music, occultic-nine

Recently I've heard the song *Play The Game's* by Asaka, which is the ending theme of the visual novel *Occultic;Nine*.

But I can neither get the proper full version of it in YouTube, nor a proper download link. How to find the full version of a song like this one?

Comment: Take note that we don't want to support piracy here (including the gray area of YouTube), so the answers we might provide will probably cost you (buying/subscribing) unless there are free licensed streaming services (e.g. Spotify) instead.

Comment: Spotify link is fine !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the song is not available on Spotify although a few of Asaka's other singles are. Additionally, it looks like the single is for sale on the Japanese iTunes, but possibly not elsewhere.

Your main legal option, it seems, is to purchase a physical copy of the single. It is available on [CDJapan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/USSW-61) and [Play Asia](https://www.play-asia.com/play-the-game-occultic-nine-edition/13/70bo2v), and possibly other import sites (but not Amazon US).